# Android Studio emulator not working correctly

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

My Android Studio emulator is running in emulation mode instead of HAXM
even though RAM size in AVD and HAXM is same (1 GB). Here is a screenshot showing my situation:

[image: Android Studio screenshot showing AVD]

Can someone explain how to make sure my emulator is running in the correct/best mode?

Comment: Please clarify your answer. Add all the necessary information as text to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HAXM stands for Hardware Accelerated eXecution Manager.  It's a technology that enables your Android Virtual Device (AVD), an emulator, to run faster under Windows.  It does not change the fact that the AVD is an emulator (vs. a virtual machine like Genymotion or Android-x86).

From the log messages in your image attachment, it looks like you are all set.  I see "HAXM is working..." there and I also see the AVD all booted up and good to go.